# Login en PHP con mysql MVC no funciona

Tags: php, html, mysql

Estoy desarrollando mi web, a partir de un miniframework, que obtuve en un ejemplo de Victor Robles:

[Ejemplo PHP POO MVC](https://victorroblesweb.es/2014/07/15/ejemplo-php-poo-mvc/#comment-1147)

Estoy implementando mi plantilla poco a poco, y por ahora no tengo mas que la vista principal, ( home ), y un enlace a otra vista.

Antes de continuar me gustaria implementar un login, y registro para mis usuarios, pero no logro hacer que funcione, aqui pongo mi codigo:

Estructura de carpetas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

LoginController.php

```
<?php
//defined('BASEPATH') or exit('No se permite acceso directo');

require_once "../model/LoginModel.php";
require_once "../core/Session.php";

/**
* Login controller
*/
class LoginController extends Controller
{
  private $model;
  private $session;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->model = new LoginModel();
    $this->session = new Session();
  }

  public function exec()
  {
    $this->render(__CLASS__);
  }

  public function signin($request_params)
  {
    if($this->verify($request_params))
      return $this->renderErrorMessage('El email y password son obligatorios');

    $result = $this->model->signIn($request_params['email']);

    if(!$result->num_rows)
      return $this->renderErrorMessage("El email {$request_params['email']} no fue encontrado");

    $result = $result->fetch_object();

    if(!password_verify($request_params['password'], $result->password))
      return $this->renderErrorMessage('La contraseña es incorrecta');

    $this->session->init();
    $this->session->add('email', $result->email);
    header('location: /php-mvc/main');
  }

  private function verify($request_params)
  {
    return empty($request_params['email']) OR empty($request_params['password']);
  }

  private function renderErrorMessage($message)
  {
    $params = array('error_message' => $message);
    $this->render(__CLASS__, $params);
  }

}
```

LoginModel.php:

```
<?php 

class LoginModel extends ModeloBase
{

  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
  }

  public function signIn($email)
  {
    $email = $this->db->real_escape_string($email);
    $sql = "SELECT email, password FROM usuarios WHERE email = '{$email}'";
    return $this->db->query($sql);
  }
}
```

En la carpeta core, he creado Session.php:

```
<?php
/**
 * Clase básica para administrar sesiones
 */
class Session
{
  /**
   * Inicializa la sesión
   */
  public function init()
  {
    session_start();
  }

  /**
   * Agrega un elemento a la sesión
   * @param string $key la llave del array de sesión
   * @param string $value el valor para el elemento de la sesión
   */
  public function add($key, $value)
  {
    $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
  }

  /**
   * Retorna un elemento a la sesión
   * @param string $key la llave del array de sesión
   * @return string el valor del array de sesión si tiene valor
   */
  public function get($key)
  {
    return !empty($_SESSION[$key]) ? $_SESSION[$key] : null;
  }

  /**
   * Retorna todos los valores del array de sesión
   * @return el array de sesión completo
   */
  public function getAll()
  {
    return $_SESSION;
  }

  /**
   * Remueve un elemento de la sesión
   * @param string $key la llave del array de sesión
   */
  public function remove($key)
  {
    if(!empty($_SESSION[$key]))
      unset($_SESSION[$key]);
  }

  /**
   * Cierra la sesión eliminando los valores
   */
  public function close()
  {
    session_unset();
    session_destroy();
  }

  /**
   * Retorna el estatus de la sesión
   * @return string el estatus de la sesión
   */
  public function getStatus()
  {
    return session_status();
  }

}
```

y la vista del login.html:

```
<form class="form-signin" method="POST" action="../../controller/LoginController.php" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
    <fieldset class="form-group position-relative has-icon-left mb-0 ">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control form-control-lg input-lg" placeholder="Introduce tu e-mail" value="" required>

     </fieldset>
     <fieldset class="form-group position-relative has-icon-left">
       <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control form-control-lg input-lg" placeholder="Introduce tu contraseña" required>
     </fieldset>
     <fieldset class="form-group row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-xs-12 text-xs-center text-md-left">
       <fieldset>
          <input type="checkbox" id="remember-me" class="chk-remember">
            <label for="remember-me">No cerrar sesión</label>
        </fieldset>
       </div>
      </fieldset>
```

Login

Al tratar de iniciar sesión me devuelve un HTTP ERROR 500.

Podrían aclararme un poco que es lo que hago mal? o que necesito para realizar esto, hasta ahora había trabajado con frameworks que esto me lo hacia automaticamente y a pesar de ver bastantes tutoriales pero no son exactamente lo que yo busco hacer.

A mi lo que me gustaria hacer seria un login, aparte de la web, que puedes iniciar sesion o no para andar por la pagina, pero para algunas secciones necesites estar registrado.

Muchas gracias por su atención anticipado.

Edito: php_error.log de mamp:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'ModeloBase' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mvc/model/LoginModel.php on line 5
```

Por lo que entiendo, al llamar al login.html, no esta haciendo la llamada al controlador correctamente.

Saludos.

Comment: Un error 500 podría ser un error de sintaxis en el código PHP. ¿Podrías consultar el log de error del servidor apache para ver qué te aparece allí? Suele llamarse `error_log` o `error.log`.

Comment: Por cierto, huye rápidamente de esa web, aléjate tanto como puedas. Esa página promueve malas prácticas como `public function getById($id){ $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE id=$id"); ...` que son barbaridades.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta @OscarGarcia, primero que nada, me podrias decir cual seria la buena practica de ese ejemplo entonces? la verdad que estoy bastante perdido. Y ahora mismo miro el log. Edito mi pregunta

Comment: `SELECT * FROM $this->table WHERE id=$id` es muy vulnerable a inyección sql. Para solventar eso usa consultas preparadas. https://secure.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: Se trata de [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyección_SQL), es [un peligro serio de seguridad para tu aplicación](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY&t=934s). Se usan consultas preparadas en lugar de concatenación de cadenas.

Comment: Problema localizado. Si no usas un cargador automático de clases (como el que dispone `composer`) deberás incluir explícitamente el archivo que contiene la definición de `ModeloBase` en tu `LoginModel.php` haciendo uso de, por ejemplo, `require_once`.

Comment: He realizado los cambios y el login no me da error, pero a vista principal no me funciona, me dice esto: 
Warning: require_once(../core/ModeloBase.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mvc/model/LoginModel.php on line 5

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '../core/ModeloBase.php' (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.10/lib/php') in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mvc/model/LoginModel.php on line 5
Creo que el problema que tengo es que no doy enlazado el home con el login digamos

Comment: Todo depende de la ruta en la que tengas el subdirectorio `core` respecto del `model` en el que se aloja tu PHP. Teóricamente lo estás haciendo bien, pero deberías cerciorarte que el archivo está allí.

Comment: Esta ahi, antes de añadir el login todo funcionaba correctamente, he de decir que el login lo he como añadido aparte , con lo cual no se si lo tengo completamente implementado al codigo, yo lo que queria era limitar solo algunas zonas de mi web, pero no tengo ni pajolera idea de como hacerlo, ya bastante me cuesta la forma "facil" no te preocupes, supongo que en esto ya me tengo que buscar la vida, gracias igualmente por tu ayuda :)

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con que está a parte? Si nos compartes la estructura de directorios podremos ayudarte a generar una ruta relativa al archivo. En caso contrario tendrás que ir investigando cuál debería ser si está en un sitio diferente. Otra opción podría ser incluir el `require_once "../core/ModeloBase.php";` en el archivo `LoginController.php`, antes de requerir `LoginModel.php`. Pero te ocurrirá lo mismo si las rutas relativas no sirven o si dicho PHP está en otra ruta diferente.

Comment: Edito el post y comparto la estructura de carpetas ahora.

Comment: Si quieres te puedo intentar explicar todo mejor por el chat. Gracias por todo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90044/discussion-between-peisou-and-oscargarcia).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gracias a la ayuda de Oscar Garcia, he conseguido aclarar los fallos de uso o programación que tenia en mi código, aunque no es muy practico, y aparte de las recomendaciones todo ha sido por un fallo de autocarga de ficheros, utilizando `require_once` en los ficheros que tiraba el error gracias al log de php he podido localizar el error.

Muchas gracias.

Saludos.